# variable not storing data in derived class

Tags: inheritance, opencv

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual Process(cv::Mat& img) {}
} ;

class B : public A
{
public:

     Process(cv::Mat& inputimage)
     {

        if (img.empty())
        {
            img = inputimage.clone();
            return;
        }

       else
           cv::imshow ("image", img);
    }
private:

       cv::Mat img;

  };
```

This img, is always empty when the condition is encountered. 
The way I am using this code in my main is :

PSEUDO CODE

```
int main ()`
{
   A* a;

   a = new B;

   while(avi.notempty()
   {
       a.Process(nextFrame);
   }
}
```

The code isn't complete but essentially the problem is that the variable is not being stored somehow.

Comment: Please edit your code. As it is it's not even clear what it is supposed to do: that if branch mixed with `private:`.. strange!

Comment: if you make Process pure virtual, at least you can track, if B is implementing it correctly,                                                      `class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual Process(cv::Mat& img) =0;
} ;`

Comment: again, please edit your code, lots of errors there, Process needs a return type, a->Process instead of a.Process, etc.  don't be that sloppy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved when I changed

`img.copyTo(img2);`

to

`img2 = img.clone();`

Thanks !